# Renaming log with timestamp and string

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp

I have an issue where log files should be created twice a day. When they are about to be created the second time, it is detected that a file with that name already exists so they aren't created. What i therefore want t do is when the second run takes place, I want to rename the first log with a timestamp and perhaps a string saying "Previous".

This is what i  have atm:

> ```
> renameLogs() {
>
> for x in $MY_FILE_PATH/logs/!Previous*$TIMESTAMP.log; do
> mv "$x" "$Previous{x%*.log}$(TIMESTAMP).log";
> done
> ```
>
> }

what this does however is everytime it runs, it renames all the logs and i end up with log names like

MyLog_240220120224-15434620120224-160148.log

What I simply want to do is:

to check IF log doesn't contain Previous AND TIMESTAMP then rename log with PREVIOUS + TIMESTAMP. My knowledge to do this limited, can someone please help.

Thanks

Comment: You should check out [logrotate]( https://iain.cx/src/logrotate/ )for your distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy solution is to keep an archive dir for your named logs, so your cmd becomes

```
mv "$x" $MY_FILE_PATH/archive_logs/"${x%*.log}$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).log"
```

with the `$MY_FILE_PATH/archive_logs/` just being an example, pick a name that makes sense for you.

ELSE

you can use some other trick so the for loop doesn't match you renamed log files

```
 mv "$x" "${x%*.log}$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).LOG"
```

Notice renaming .log to .LOG

ELSE

you have to exclude the files from processing

```
renameLogs() {
   for x in $MY_FILE_PATH/logs/*.log; do
      case "${x}" in
        *2[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]* ) 
           : # if_File_has_YYYYMMDD_value_embedded_skip_this_file
        ;;
        * ) 
          mv "$x" "${x%*.log}$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).log"
        ;;
      esac
   done
}
```

OR

Hm... reformatting has stoped working! ;-/

renameLogs() {
       for x in $MY_FILE_PATH/logs/*.log; do
          if [[ ! "${x}" ~= *2[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]* ]]; then 
              mv "$x" "${x%*.log}$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).log" ;
          fi ;
       done ;
      }

Untested.

**Regular Expression** used.

Regular expressions are an extension of the wild-card idea you may be familiar with from using a command line, i.e. `ls *.txt`, will expand to only files that end in txt, excluding ones that end in .exe, .bash, .txt2, etc.

For your case, `*2[...]*` is a reg expression that matches a date (excluding the timestamp) in the format you have specified.. *= any chars,, single chars match just themselves, and the final bit of reg-ex magic is are char ranges, in this case '[0-9]' and simliar.

The `~=` operator says compare the LeftHand vs the RightHand using regular expressions.

See if `${x}` matches

```
 * any chars, 
 follow by '2', 
 followed by any number [0-9] (3 times) (a year value)
 followed by [0-1][0-9] ( a month value)
 followed by [0-3][0-9] ( a day value)
 * any chars,
```

So you can easily extend `*2[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]*` to include the word previous in the correct location so the reg-expr matches your final value of ${x}, i.e.

```
 if [[ "${x}" ~= *Previous*2[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]* ]] ; then ...
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Doesnt unix support functions like IF(log name doesnt contain Previous & TIMESTAMP), Rename the log

Comment: 1. I don't see the word Previous in the example data you posted, so I didn't know how to handle that. 2. yes, but `case` provides (for your purpose) the same functionality. I try not to use `if [[ "${x}" ~= *2[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]* ]]; then ...` unless I absolutely have to. Good luck.

Comment: I know Previous isnt in the example i posted however it in my initial question I did mentioned i wanted to incorporate that. Could you please clarify what *2[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]* ]]; means? Thanks

Comment: I can't guess what you mean by Previous. If I answer it one way based on non-sample data, please edit your post to include sample input, and expected output. I'll edit in an explanation on 2[0-9]..., which is call a regular expression.

Comment: edited. Not sure if syntaxt is right hough but that is what i would like it to do. Many Thanks

Comment: I appreciate your help however isnt there a shorter way of doing this? Something like (Writing in pseudocode here) IF Log name is not start with Previous and end with Timestamp, Add it.

Comment: What shell are you using. Most people seem to use bash, but `ksh93+` supports a !(Previous) syntax, but it is **very** hard to get right. That would be creating a maintenance night-mare. So basically, there is no simpiler way to do this. I leave it open to others post their solutions that prove me wrong ;-) Good luck.

Comment: sorry for the late reply,  I use ksh. Still havent found a way to fix this... :(